# Is there a working package for native FB login?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

The most-recently-updated one I could find was https://github.com/particle4dev/meteor-accounts-facebook-cordova (repo way ahead of atmosphere version), but I wasn't able to get it working (see last two comments here: https://github.com/particle4dev/meteor-cordova-facebook-login/issues/1).

Comment: Were you able to get the *particle4dev facebook package* working? I think its still not updated on github with the correct documentation. 
After following the existing documentation, it shows "Meteor settings for accounts-facebook-cordova not configured correctly".

Instead of using this package, is it better to implement Meteor.loginWithFacebook and cordova facebook separately?

Comment: I wasn't. `vicentealencar:cordova-fb` works for me though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vicentealencar:cordova-fb                     1.1.9  Login service for Facebo...
```

Uses the same `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` calls in browser and Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this and its been working great - https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-facebook

What exactly isnt working for you?

1. Do you have API keys set up?
2. Are you calling Meteor.loginWithFacebook?

This is a pretty good tutorial http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/

Comment: Sorry, by native I meant it takes you to the FB app and back, rather than showing you a webpage within your UIWebView.

Comment: this was so annoying to search for a native Facebook login solution because people don't understand "native".